# Detect/handle all collision from one script or script not attached to the collision GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to control triggers between player and power-ups. Instead of creating a script for each one, can I create one GameObject and attach a script to control all trigger event?

Like

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
    switch(collision.gameObject.tag){
        case "Move+":
            FindObjectOfType<CreatePlayer>().movesRemain += 5;
            break;
    }
}
```

but when doing this, the player must trigger the GameObject that contains script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Instead of creating a script for each one, can I create one GameObject
>   and attach a script to control all trigger event?

For `OnTriggerEnter2D` to be invoked, the script that contains it must be attached to that GameObject that will be involved in the collision. If this is not done, it won't be invoked.

---

If you need a general script to handle all the collision detection, you will have to use event and delegate to do that. Create a `delegate` named `CollisionAction` then an event from that `delegate` named `OnTriggered`. When `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called, invoke that `OnTriggered` event. *Attach it to all the GameObjects you want to detect the collision on.*

```
public class CollisionCallback : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void CollisionAction(Collider2D collision);
    public static event CollisionAction OnTriggered;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (OnTriggered != null)
            OnTriggered(collision);
    }
}
```

Now, on the main script you want to use to handle the collision, register to the `OnTriggered` event in the `OnEnable` function and un-register it in the `OnDisable` function. *When `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called in the `CollisionCallback` script, the registered function in the `MainScript` would be called*. Attach to an empty GameObject:

```
public class MainScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register to OnTriggered event
        CollisionCallback.OnTriggered += TriggerDetected;
    }


    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register to OnTriggered event
        CollisionCallback.OnTriggered -= TriggerDetected;
    }


    //This is invoked when trigger happens
    void TriggerDetected(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger happened with: " + collision.name);
    }
}
```